# IE 7 meta tag in condition

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, conditional-comments

When I add meta tag in if condition it destroy the UI
[image]

```
  <!--[if IE lt 10]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><![endif]-->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



<link id="lnkStyleSheet" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
<link href="~/Style/Controls.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>
```

As you can see in the IE 7 browser it shows in the background.

Comment: Need to see your full HTML.

Comment: Try this <!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->

Comment: I have modified my question. is this information is sufficient or you require some more ?

Comment: HI Shibin. after adding your code !--[if IE 7] even the meta tag is not displaying now in IE7 in head section. i checked it using inspect elment. can you provide me exact line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have IE lt rather than lt IE? Try this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /><![endif]-->
```